# Custom html Wordpress Comments with avatar and reply

Tags: php, html, wordpress, comments

I am developing a theme and has no idea how wordpress handles the comment outputs.

I have`wp_list_comments` in my `comments.php`, but I'm not sure how to customize the output to get the desired output like this :

[image]

this my html code :

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
      <img src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/person-flat.png" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <h4>John Row <small>Sep 25, 2015, 8:25 PM</small></h4>
      <p>I am so happy for you man! Finally. I am looking forward to read about your trendy life. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      <br>
      <p><span class="badge">1</span> Comment:</p><br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-center">
          <img src="http://www.noviasalcedo.es/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/person-girl-flat.png" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
        </div>
        <dsiv class="col-xs-10">
          <h4>Nested Bro <small>Sep 25, 2015, 8:28 PM</small></h4>
          <p>Me too! WOW!</p>
          <br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any suggestions on how to customize the output rendered by `wp_list_comments` ?

#### #update

`comments.php`:

```
<div id="comments" class="comments-area">

    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <h2 class="comments-title">
            <?php
                $comments_number = get_comments_number();

                    printf(
                        /* translators: 1: number of comments, 2: post title */
                        _nx(
                            '<p><span class="badge">%1$s</span> Comments:</p><br>',
                            '<p><span class="badge">%1$s</span> Comments:</p><br>',
                            $comments_number,
                            'comments title'
                        ),
                        number_format_i18n( $comments_number )
                    );
            ?>
        </h2>




<ol class="commentlist">
    <?php wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=mytheme_comment');
   ?>
</ol><!-- .commentlist -->


    <?php endif; // Check for have_comments(). ?>



    <?php
        comment_form( array(
            'title_reply_before' => '<h2 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">',
            'title_reply_after'  => '</h2>',
        ) );
    ?>

</div><!-- .comments-area -->
```

Comment: This seems like something that the theme would handle, what theme are you using?

Comment: my own Theme  .. @Daniel By bootstrap

Comment: @Daniel he is writing the theme. Take a look at `Walker_Comment()` function

Comment: Can you update your post to include the comments.php?

Comment: @Daniel I did #update

Comment: The HTML that you posted, is that what your page is rendering for comments? It doesn't look like the standard Wordpress comments, I'm expecting to see an `<ol>` element at the very least

Comment: @Daniel I want without `<ol>`, that would be better for the design

Comment: Ok but I'm worried that the code you displayed in your question isn't what was generated by your theme since it does not appear to follow what WordPress would generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the callback function on wp_list_comments() function.

```
wp_list_comments();
```

Usually, you will find this line in comments.php file of your wordpress theme. And the output from this command is a pretty straightforward HTML structure.

Wordpress have a option of passing the callback function as an argument to wp_list_comments function.

This callback function should return the modified HTML structure of comments section, which we are looking to implement.

```
<ul class="comment-list comments">
    <?php
    wp_list_comments( array(
        'style'      => 'ul',
        'short_ping' => true,
            'callback' => 'better_comments'
    ) );
     ?>
</ul><!-- .comment-list -->
```

You can check detailed tutorial here

https://www.5balloons.info/custom-html-for-comments-section-in-wordpress-theme/

Answer (score 0):

You can override the template using the `wp_list_comments` function.

[Refer to this link](http://www.studiograsshopper.ch/code-snippets/customising-wp_list_comments/).

You can put that code inside of a function and call that from the wp_list_comments as a callback. All the info on how to do that is in that link.